# fresh install of Android Studio + emulator, emulator eating CPU + battery

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, macos-catalina

I've got a fresh Catalina install along with Android Studio. Turns out when I launch an emulator, the emulator process grabs a ton of CPU cycles. Looking at `top` in `adb shell`, I get a number of processes I don't understand.

This basically makes my dev environment unusable as I can watch my battery drain in seconds, and my laptop heats way up.

Suggestions ???

[image: activity monitor]
[image: top]

Comment: Emulator acts like normal mobile device and now comes with *google play store or google play service* pre-installed *(Depending upon how you setup emulator)*. So processes you're looking at are related to google play services, some of them might be system processes too.

Comment: I'm still on the older version of Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6 on a 2012 MacBook Air and when I run an emulator `qemu-system-x86_64` my "%CPU" in Activity Monitor is around 12-15%. So with some more detail about your setup, others might able to provide data points.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:
 1. Install android studio ( Do not install any emulator)
 2. Open a sample project in Android-studio
 3. Open any layout file
 4. Click on phone tab ( near device rotation tab)
 5. Click on Add device definition. 
 6. Click on Create Virtual Device.
 7. Select the device you want and once it's downloaded and installed, run the project with that device.

Now check your battery performance

Comment: update your android studio once, this has new inside emulator so u can use that, this emulator will not take any extra ram usage and memory. This may help to get bit of battery backup

Comment: I'm on the latest  Android Studio but the resource and battery usage are the same as before.

Comment: No haven't tried that. But that will also consume battery as you can't expect an emulator to be running and system using the battery as it uses in idle. Emulation is a pretty CPU intensive task.

Comment: yes, it will but some emulators like nox consume less than others like browser stack, tencent